# How can I put a flag on certain tags?

Tags: support, tags, flagging

Is there a way to flag certain tags such as this one with is identical to another one https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rpi-3b

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot flag tags. Just bring the issue up on meta (like you did) to have the tag either deleted or synomynized with another.

I merged it with [pi-3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-3) which is canonical for this model. Thanks for bringing it up!

Comment: How can I merge tags?

Comment: Afaik that is a mod-only feature. You can, however, initiate tag synonyms at [2500 rep](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms).